# split command in scala not working fine with special character like ~

Tags: scala, split

hi I have string like this :

```
var ma_test="~0.000000~~~"
```

I am using the split function with ~ as delimiter but it did not split correctly

what I try :

```
scala>  var ma_test="~0.000000~~~"
scala>  val split_val = ma_test.split("~")
    split_val: Array[String] = Array("", 0.000000)
scala>  val split_dis = split_val(2)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

... 32 elided

I try also to use val split_val = ma_test.split("\~") and ma_test.split('~') still not able to split correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using split will remove all the trailing empty strings, so there are 2 elements after split (as the leading ~ will also split), and starting from index 0, 1 etc..

Note that you get the first empty entry in the Array, as there is a ~ at the start that will also split, so you should use index 1.

```
var ma_test="~0.000000~~~"
val split_val = ma_test.split("~")
val split_dis = split_val(1)
```

Output

```
var ma_test: String = ~0.000000~~~
val split_val: Array[String] = Array("", 0.000000)
val split_dis: String = 0.000000
```

You can pass -1 as the second argument to see all parts, and using index 2 will then give you an empty string.

```
var ma_test="~0.000000~~~"
val split_val = ma_test.split("~", -1)
val split_dis = split_val(2)
```

Output

```
var ma_test: String = ~0.000000~~~
val split_val: Array[String] = Array("", 0.000000, "", "", "")
val split_dis: String = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is the same with a "special character" `~` or the character `x` which suggests the the split function is not the issue. In either case if you try and access `split_val(2)` you will get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` since that index does not exist in the array. `0` or `1` will work ok.

```
scala> var ma_test="x0.000000xxx"
var ma_test: String = x0.000000xxx
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
scala> ma_test.split("x")
val res1: Array[String] = Array("", 0.000000)

scala> var ma_test="~0.000000~~~"
var ma_test: String = ~0.000000~~~
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
scala> ma_test.split("~")
val res0: Array[String] = Array("", 0.000000)
```